# How can I truncate uploaded file name

Tags: files

Can anyone suggest a way, or a module to truncate very long filenames which are uploaded to a Drupal 7 website? I have a client who keeps uploading files that are actually sentences and I want to limit the filename to a reasonable and certain amount of characters (say 20).

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a presave hook and rename the file before it gets saved: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_presave/7